# Python matrix finding indexes

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have the following problem with my code, I would like to search in a 2d array a specific number and return all indexes where this number occurs.

```
matrix = [[0]*10 for _ in range(10)]

# Populate the matrix with some digit that I would like to search later on

matrix[0][0], matrix[1][2:5], matrix[3][2] = 1, [1 for x in range(4)], 1

# This actually looks as follow

[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now I would like to find all indexes where 1 occurs in the matrix

```
[(index, row.index(1)) for index, row in enumerate(matrix) if 1 in row]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (3, 2)]
```

This actually returns me only the first occurance in the first row. I tried as well with two for loops but behaviour is the same.

Any advices are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The following gives all indices where the element equals one in the matrix:

```
[(row,column) for row in range(10) for column in range(10) if matrix[row][column]==1]
```

output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Index only returns the first occurence of the value in the array.

What you COULD do, if you want to use `index()` is when you find `offset` of the first value in a line, call the same on `array[offset+1:]` until there's no more.

On the other hand, a simpler version to write is @joostblack's answer, which simply crawls the whole array one by one.